# Problem when creating a network with my virtual machine

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I have installed a VirtualBox with an Ubuntu Server (16.04)on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop.

I want to create a virtual network. By reading some post on the web, it seems pretty simple but ...

So, I have configured like that:

- In VirtualBox settings > network: NAT is empty, and in Host Only, I have vboxnet0 with 192.168.56.1 as IP, 255.255.255.0 as mask and DHCP empty
- I setup the virtual server, with card 1 = NAT and Private Host with name vboxnet0 and Authorize all.
  Checkbox cable plugged is tick on.
- File /etc/network/interface contain this informations:

  auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

  auto enp0s3
    iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.26.70
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.56.1
    gateway 192.168.56.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

I try to ping host and guest but nothing is working. I miss something but what ?

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE 1**
Screenshots about configuration
[image: ifconfig on VM]
[image: Settings]
[image: /etc/network/interfaces]

I know I miss something but what?

Comment: I need more info to help you....do you need internet on that VM?

Comment: Yes. When I ping google it is working. If I ping hosting machine it is also working. But whenever I ping guest from host it says Unreachable.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @lewis4u not yet. I will do it this evening (I am in Europa ;-) . And I will give you a feedback immediately afterward. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: @lewis4u  no, it doesn't work. I added some screenshots

Comment: why adapter 2....what is under adapter 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45429/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-jonathan-lebrun).

Comment: Sorry but it was not possible at time for the chat. I commented your answer but it is not match on my requirements. But it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your network adapter to bridged and for Name: choose your host NIC - your wireless or LAN connection adapter from laptop.

Mine is Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000

Instead of that choose yours.

and press the MAC Adress refresh button (on the right the blue one with arrows) a few times[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I don't have the same Name but wslxxx (see my update). Thanks a lot

Comment: It is working fine with Bridged Adapter but it is not really I have to do. I want to create a internal network not in the same host network.

Comment: when you create internal network that  network doesn't have connection with your host.....it is isolated! you need to have two VM machines and connect them....and that is internal network....if you need more info, write here

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I will try it tomorrow and I'll give you a feedback

Comment: You can see an explanation of all 3 basic types of networking for VirtualBox - Just a hint when he says "Instance" that is actually the virtual machine!!! https://youtu.be/AiWRmMzwwJM?t=1182

Answer (score 0):

If you want

1. to be able to ping the host
2. to have a private IP belonging to a private network

then, as suggested above by lewis4u's answer's comments, you need to create an Internal network instead of a Bridged network:

[image: Network adapter 1: interface to the host]
[image: network adapter 2: interface to the Internal network]

Then you should get two interfaces, one NATed and thus connected to the Internet (if your host is), and one allowing to communicate within the internal network.

PS: your line "network 192.168.56.1" in /etc/network/interfaces seems extraneous (look `man 5 interfaces`).